# Structure of first-coordinate-projection of set of solutions of "elliptic" diophantine equation $xy(6-(x+y))=6$

Tags: diophantine-equations, dynamical-systems, elliptic-curves

Say that a rational number $a$ is good iff there is a rational number $b$
with $ab(6-a-b)=6$, or equivalently iff $a^4 - 12a^3 + 36a^2 - 24a$
 is the square of a rational number. Denote by $G$ the set of all good 
 numbers.

It is known that $G$ is infinite ; moreover, elaborate algebraic manipulation
shows that $G$ is invariant by the transformation

$$f(a)=\frac{-54a(-6+12a-6a^2+a^3)^2}
{−216+1296a^2−2160a^3+1296a^4−108a^5−234a^6+108a^7−18a^8+a^9}$$

(see Aretino's comment on Tito Piezas' answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1384653/rational-solutions-to-abc-abc-6))

Also, $G$ clearly contains $1,2,3,8$.If we denote the roots of
$a^3 - 12a^2 + 36a - 24$ by $t_1<t_2<t_3$, then clearly
$G\subseteq (-\infty,0] \cup [t_1,t_2] \cup [t_3,\infty)$.

Can more be said about the structure of $G$ ? For example,
is $G$ bounded ? Does $G$ have an accumulation point ? What can be
said about the closure of $G$ ?

Comment: well if i followed everything correctly, the curve has positive rank and so its rational points are either dense in both real components, or dense in the component of the identity, so after quotienting / looking at the $x$ component, your set will be either dense in $[t_3,0]$ or dense in $[t_3,0] \cup [t_1,t_2]$

Comment: @mercio I'm not very familiar with elliptic curves and I must be missing something, but how does a positive rank garantee density ? If I understood correctly, here we have an elliptic curve of rank 1, so the group has a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$. But ${\mathbb Z}\times \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$ and yet is not dense anywhere

Comment: @EwanDelanoy: You may be interested to know that the irreducible nonic denominator has a solvable Galois group. I have no idea why. Pls see [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391806/).

Comment: "Isomorphic to Z" *as an abstract group*, but you're putting it in a compact topological group that's the union of two circles.  Within each circle it's like the multiples of $\sqrt 2 \mod 1$, which is dense (the closure is a closed subgroup, and any proper closed subgroups of the circle is finite).

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies thanks for your clear explanation.